# code not entering while loop in two sums problem

Tags: python

I wrote a binary search based solution to the two sums problems, this one https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/ . for the given case, the program seems to be falling out of the loop and not considering the case start=end=0 and entering the while loop for the case suggested despite the while (end>=start) condition. feeling like a complete tool, can't seem to figure out what's going on.

```
def BinarySearchWork(lis, target, prick):
    start = 0
    pick = prick[0]
    control = prick[1]
    length = len(lis)
    end = length - 1
    while (end >= start ):
        midpoint = int(((end + start) / 2))
        if lis[midpoint] + pick >= target:
            end = midpoint - 1
        if lis[midpoint] + pick <= target:
            start = midpoint + 1
        if lis[midpoint] + pick == target:
            if midpoint == control:
                continue
            else:
                return (midpoint)
                print(midpoint)
        else:
            return(False)



def twoSum(nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    pick = 0
    nums1 = sorted(nums)
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        pick = [nums1[i], i]
        if (BinarySearchWork(nums1, target, pick)):
            return [i, BinarySearchWork(nums1, target, pick)]

twoSum([3,2,4],6)
```

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: `print(midpoint)` will never be executed since it's after `return midpoint`.

Comment: Your `else:` statement is only connected to the last `if`. You should be using a series of `elif` statements so that `else:` is only executed if none of them are true. Although your 3 conditions cover all the possibilities, so it's not clear when you expect the `else:` to be executed at all.

Comment: @Barmar those were written in desperation because i could not figure out why 
twoSum([3,2,4],6) kept falling out of the loop when start=end= 0 according to debugger

Comment: I'll bet it's in `else: return False`. Add a print statement there to see.

Comment: yeah i put a print statement before the final else, looks like the code is somehow ending up in the last else block

Comment: It ends up there whenever the condition `if lis[midpoint] + pick == target:` fails, because you used `if` instead of `elif`.

Comment: It's executing the final `else` case because, as @Barmar commented, the `else` is **only** connected to the preceding `if`.  It looks like you should have used `if/elif/elif/else`, so that the final `else` would only be executed if **all** of the preceding conditions were false.  But instead you used `if/if/if/else`, so the `else` is executed when the immediately preceding `if` is false, without caring if the first two `ifs` were true.

Comment: TIL that if and elif function differently, i changed by thing to if/elif/elif/else, the print statement before the final else didn't print, but seems like the program is still falling out of the while loop somehow

Comment: And as I said above, that last case can never really happen. Either it's less than, greater than, or equal to the target, there's no other possibility (unless you have NaN in the list or target). You should only return False if you get through the entire loop without returning.

Comment: Note that if the function returns `0`, that will be treated as false by the `if` statement.

Comment: @Barmar that turned out to be it, i had two problems with the code, the else vs elif and the if accepting 0 as false. Thanks

Comment: Don't call `BinarySearchWork()` twice. Assign the result to a variable so you can test it and then return it from `twoSum()`.